# How to check paramiko version installed?

Tags: python, paramiko

I have installed paramiko 1.15.2 on Linux machine. But i want to know its version via command. Is there any command that prints out version of paramiko installed?

Comment: is there not a `version` attribute? so `paramiko.version`?

Comment: it does, https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/_version.py

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get it via the `__version__` attribute.

```
#First, run python directly from terminal:
python
...
>>> import paramiko
>>> print paramiko.__version__
1.12.0
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also

```
pip show paramiko
```

Output would look like this

```
pip show paramiko
---
Name: paramiko
Version: 1.15.2
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: pycrypto, ecdsa
```

Comment: this worked for me but the other commands didn't (I'm on python 2.7)

Answer (score 2):

```
print paramiko.__version__
```

Output:

```
'1.10.1'
```